# Особенности разбора wsdl файлов утилитами Microsoft

Tags: c#, wsdl

Никак не удается найти нужный набор ключей командной строки при использовании Microsoft-ских утилит wsdl.exe и svcutil.exe. Задача тривиальная, разобрать комплект .wsdl и .xsd файлов и сгенерировать для них набор исходных файлов на C#, содержащих код, описывающий интерфейсы взаимодействия и типы данных, которые можно использовать при работе с удаленным веб сервисом.

Используя утилиту wsimport из JDK, проблема решается очень легко и я могу получить набор исходников, а могу даже получить сразу упакованную  в jar библиотеку используя к примеру вот такой сценарий shell:

```
#!/bin/sh

rm -rf build/*
rm -rf src/*
rm -rf bin/GisWsServices.jar

for item in `ls -1 wsdls/*.wsdl`
do

echo ""
echo "Begin processing $item file..."

wsimport -XadditionalHeaders -extension -s src -d build $item

echo ""
done

echo "Make jar library..."
echo "..."
cd build
jar cf ../bin/GisWsServices.jar ru org
```

Ключевая строка в этом сценарии начинается словом "wsimport". Для Microsoft-ских утилит не удалось подобрать аналога именно этой строки, чтобы получить аналогичный результат, но исходники на C#. Комплект wsdl файлов можно к примеру взять с портала Госуслуг ГИС ЖКХ (dom.gosuslugi.ru) из раздела Регламенты и инструкции, файл там обычно называется Регламенты и форматы информационного взаимодействия внешних информационных систем. Внутри этого архива есть еще один архив с wsdl-ями.

**Обновление**

Как я пытаюсь трансформировать wsdl описания в исходный код на C# и что в результате мне не нравится? В простейшем виде я буквально пытаюсь выполнить сценарий командной строки Windows вот такого содержания:

```
for /r %i in (7.1.0.2\*.wsdl) do wsdl /out:src /sharetypes File:///%i
```

В ответ, частично, вместо исходников на C# я получаю вот такие сообщения об ошибках:

> Error: Не удается импортировать привязку "NsiBinding" из пространства имен "http
>   ://dom.gosuslugi.ru/schema/integration/7.1.0.2/nsi-service/".
>    - Не удается импортировать операцию "importMunicipalServices".
>    - Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

С помощью кода тех исходников, которые у меня все же генерируются, я не могу отправлять запросы веб сервисам, потому что сигнатуры сгенерированных методов получаются урезанные, и сформировать правильный запрос невозможно. Например сигнатура метода на Java выглядит так:

```
public ExportOrgRegistryResult exportOrgRegistry(
    ExportOrgRegistryRequest exportOrgRegistryRequest,
    ISRequestHeader header,
    Holder<ResultHeader> header0)
```

А сигнатура того же самого метода на C# выглядит так:

```
public exportOrgRegistryResult exportOrgRegistry(
    exportOrgRegistryRequest exportOrgRegistryRequest)
```

**Проблема при использовании утилиты svcutil.exe**

В случае, когда я пытаюсь воспользоваться утилитой svcutil.exe используя к примеру простейшую командную строку (в данном случае все xsd файлы указаны один раз, для ускорения редактирования данной публикации):

```
for /r %i in (7.1.0.2\*.wsdl) do svcutil.exe %i .\7.1.0.2\hcs-basetypes-7.1.0.2.xsd .\7.1.0.2\hcs-bills-types-7.1.0.2.xsd .\7.1.0.2\hcs-device-metering-types-7.1.0.2.xsd .\7.1.0.2\hcs-disclosure-types-7.1.0.2.xsd .\7.1.0.2\hcs-house-management-types-7.1.0.2.xsd .\7.1.0.2\hcs-infrastructure-types-7.1.0.2.xsd .\7.1.0.2\hcs-inspection-types-7.1.0.2.xsd .\7.1.0.2\hcs-licenses-types-7.1.0.2.xsd .\7.1.0.2\hcs-nsi-types-7.1.0.2.xsd .\7.1.0.2\hcs-organizations-registry-types-7.1.0.2.xsd .\7.1.0.2\hcs-payment-types-7.1.0.2.xsd .\7.1.0.2\hcs-services-types-7.1.0.2.xsd .\7.1.0.2\xmldsig-core-schema.xsd
```

Файлы исходного кода сразу генерируются, но проблема с нарушением (разницей с исходниками на Java) сигнатур методов сохраняется.

Плюс еще добавляется одна проблема, базовые типы данных, которые используются всеми без исключения веб сервисами, получают множественное объявление, во всех исходных файлах. Как получить исходник с их декларацией всего один раз для всех сервисов, тоже понять не могу.

Comment: первая строчка поиска в гугле по запросу *how to generate client code from wsdl c#* дает ответ на все вопросы

Comment: Вы бы не могли описать в своём вопросе главное - чем конкретно вас не устраивают класcы генерируемые wsdl.exe? И да, почему вам вообще требуется использовать утилиты командной строки? В студии это обычно делается через Web Service Refrence'ы.

Comment: Утилиты командной строки позволяют автоматизировать процесс сборки библиотеки для взаимодействия с веб сервисами, описания которых меняются каждые две недели. Мне нужно чтобы никто в принципе не делал этого руками, в частности потому что систему должен собирать Jenkins. В настоящий момент я предпринимаю еще одну попытку реализовать сценарий для командной строки Windows, аналогичный приведенному мной. Как только мне это не удастся, я прикомментирую здесь конкретные ошибки, если таки в этот раз удастся, то я просто удалю этот вопрос.

Comment: @SergeyEgorov, ну оно в любом случае руками никогда не обновляется, а только в сценариях сборки(обычно как шаг msbuild) - что через Web Service Reference(svcutil), что с помощью wsdl.exe.. Только вы так и не ответили на мой вопрос - чем вас конкретно не устраивают те классы, которые генерируются svcutil/wsdl сейчас?

Comment: @Sergey Rufanov для начала собственно тем, что они не генерируются. К примеру выполняю я команду for /r %i in (7.1.0.2\*.wsdl) do wsdl /out:src /sharetypes File:///%i  в ответ получаю ошибки, к примеру Error: Не удается импортировать привязку "NsiBIndingAsync" из пространства имен... Я чуть позже выложу описание процесса, как я пытаюсь это сделать, и что получаю в ответ. P.S. в папке 7.1.0.2, которая вышеупомянута в команде, собственно лежит комплект wsdl и xsd файлов.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос описанием части возникающих проблем при использовании утилиты wsdl.exe.

Comment: @Dmitry можно уточнить какого конкретно параметра командной строки утилиты wsdl.exe из тех, что явно рекомендованы документацией производителя или в ответах, указанных на stackoverflow в данном случае, я не указываю?

Comment: @SergeyEgorov доберусь до компьютера, посмотрю внимательно, сейчас в дороге

Comment: @SergeyEgorov попробовал, да, действительно, мистика какая то. тоже не получилось корректно получить файлы. может стоит написать в тех поддержку гос услуг?

Comment: @Dmitry Госуслуги практикуют разработку на Java. Инструменты из JDK без проблем собирают исполняемую библиотеку из их wsdl-ей. Так что у них все хорошо. Пожалуй в данном случае придется писать в техподдержку Microsoft.